# How to maintain a Id value throughout my Asp.net MVC application session management

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies, session-variables, session-state

How to maintain a Id value throughout my Asp.net MVC application after login -- Persist ID throughout ASP.NET MVC application?

I tried using session variable like this in login controller

```
[HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult LoginPage(UserLogin login)
            {
              else if (string.Compare(CryptoCode.Hash(login.Password), v.PPassword) == 0)
                {
                    int timeout = login.RememberMe ? 60 : 60; // 525600 min = 1 year
                    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(login.EmailID, login.RememberMe, timeout);
                    string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
                    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    var profile = db.Profile.Where(x => x.UserLoginId == v.UserLoginId).FirstOrDefault();
                    Session["PId"] = profile.PId;

                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(login.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(login.ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                               return Redirect("/ProfilePage/fileupload/index");
                    }
}
```

In my Another Controller top level

```
public ActionResult MainPage()
        {
 if (Session["PId"] != null)
        {
            Int64 pid = (Int64)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["PId"];
......
......
        }
        else
        {
            return View("~/Registration/Registration/loginpage");
        }
}
```

In web.config file

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Registration/loginpage" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true"></forms>
</authentication>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60"></sessionState>
```

when i close browser the session value getting null but my session login is active, so i get null reference exception or pid null.

In my application i have many controllers that have many action methods. i am not interested to check if condition session value in every action method.

How to maintain a session value after browser close and reopen in given timeout in session (like 20 min)?